# Как сделать Distinct для List<T>?

Tags: c#

Есть json, который я десериализовал в класс. Загружаю в cписок List. Хочу выбрать уникальные данные по параметру `id`. Использовал `MoreLinq`, yо он видит только `data`

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string public_role_id { get; set; }
    public int oref { get; set; }
    public string[] conference_topic_ids { get; set; }
    public string conference_industry_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? deleted_at { get; set; }
    public bool hidden { get; set; }
    public Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: приведи пример данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Стоп, а `Distinct` коллекция может принимать только 2 типа, у вас этого нет. Вот и не видит. И хорошо бы показать сам `json`.

Comment: @Radzhab неужто не помогло?

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно так:

```
var distinctLstByProp = 
    someList
    .GroupBy (p => p.id)
    .Select  (grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Или использовать MoreLINQ и `DistinctBy()` метод

```
var distinctLstByProp = someList.DistinctBy(p => p.id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать свой IEqualityComparer и передавать его в параметр метода Distinct() или реализовать интерфейс IEquatable и Distinct будет сам использовать реализацию этого интерфейса для сравнения.

Создаем приватный класс внутри Datum:

```cs
        private sealed class IdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Datum>
        {
            public bool Equals(Datum x, Datum y)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
                if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
                if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
                return string.Equals(x.id, y.id);
                // тут можно дополнительно кастомизировать правила сравнения 
и зависимости от других полей. Например сделать case insensitive сравнение строк.

            }

            public int GetHashCode(Datum obj)
            {
                return (obj.id != null ? obj.id.GetHashCode() : 0);
            }
        }

       // наружу выставляем статическое свойство с единственным экземпляром.
        public static IEqualityComparer<Datum> IdComparer { get; } = new IdEqualityComparer();
```

Использование:

```cs
var uniqDatumsList = nonUniqDatumsList.Distinct(Datum.IdEqualityComparer);
```

с интерфейсом IEquatable чуть по-другому - его нужно просто реализовать, а Distinct уже сам его будет использовать при сравнении и передавать уже ничего не нужно. Плюс в сторону IEqualityComparer в том, что их может быть много под разные кейсы, а IEquatable будет один на все случаи и нужно учесть различные нюансы реализации GetHashCode и Equals. Поэтому IEqualityComparer тут подходит лучше.